# how to get count of projects when the order of combination of ids should be considered as same. ,

Tags: mysql, sql

### There is a table temp containing following input values:

**input values:**

```
##Proj_Name Cust_ID  ##
proj1       qw12345 : cd12345   
proj2       cd12345 : qw12345  
proj3       ab54321 : pk12345  
proj4       pk12345 : ab54321  
proj5       ab12345  
proj6       pk12345  
proj7
```

Customer ids column is of datatype varchar. Customer ids column can consist of   one id (only one customer will be associated with the project)  or combination   of 2 ids separated with colon(means two customers are associated with the   project) or may be there will be no entry that means it will hold null value.   The customer id will be of 7 characters ,starting 2 characters will be alphabet   and rest will be numbers `**e.g. ab12345, fd78965.**`

i want to get the count of project which a Customer holds group by Customer Ids   . One more thing `**cust_ID** qw12345 : cd12345 and cd12345 : qw12345` should be   treated as same and so forth.

so **OUTPUT** should be like this

```
##count Cust_ID  ##
2   qw12345 : cd12345  
2   ab54321 : pk12345  
1   ab12345  
1   pk12345  
1   NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a very poor data format.  You should not be storing lists of things in a string.  Why not have two columns?

However, with only two values, you can do string manipulation to do what ou want:

```
select (case when cust_id like '% : %'
             then concat_ws(' : ',
                            least(substring_index(cust_id, ' : ', 1), substring_index(cust_id, ' : ', -1)),
                            greatest(substring_index(cust_id, ' : ', 1), substring_index(cust_id, ' : ', -1))
                           )
             else cust_id
         end) as new_cust_id, count(*)
from t
group by new_cust_id;
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff

Comment: can you please elaborate the functions which you used as these are not   the inbuilt functions .. i am little confused with the purpose of the   functions .  
Any help will be appreciated.  
@Gordon

Comment: @N_D . . . `least()`, `greatest()`, and `substring_index()` are all MySQL functions.  This is easy enough to check in the documentation.

Comment: my bad .. i am working in sql not familiar with mysql. Thank you @Gordon